# Redirect after Post

Tags: php, zend-framework, redirect

After form (method POST) submission i want redirect user to specific page.

usually i used simple line

```
header("Location: /path/to/redirect/");
exit;
```

The **Zend_Controller_Action** have method **_redirect** example:

```
$this->_redirect("/path/to/redirect/");
```

But it have one simple **problem**: if i **refresh page** (press F5) last controller action is activated. So its like double post.
Of course i can use old fashion way, but I just want find the zend style redirect.

*Edit: p.s after post redirect i want have cleaned form data. Of course i can use own method with header("location:/path") but I searching it implemented in standart zf*

Any ideas?

Comment: +1 I've also had this question before. I still use the `header` redirect.

Comment: _redirect($url, array $options = array()): redirect to another location. This method takes a URL and an optional set of options. By default, it performs an HTTP 302 redirect. It is your browser doing the repost, not zend

Comment: @Byron Whitlock: I know it's browsers issue. Just searching for better practises in this step;
After refresh it just called old controller action with same form data. If where was no validation so you can example fake votes results.
I just haven't found the way to use standart zf method.

Answer (score 2):

I think thats because _redirect uses an internal redirect. You need to use an external one. You need to use the Redirector action helper directly... in your action:

```
$this->_redirector->gotoUrlAndExit($url);
```

Answer (score -1):

Set a session variable that data has been posted, if not post data, redirect?

Comment: I think the point of his question, the ZF redirect helper leaves the posted data hanging around and a refresh tries to re-submit it. Even if he puts in the usual safegaurds for protecting against a repost the user gets the annoying 'You are about to resubmit data' pop-up. I assume his question is, is there something better/different/more preferred than using the `header` redirect method that removes the form data.

Comment: @manyxcxi: yes you are right. I just want remove form data after redirect.

Comment: i don't need post data saved (thats is'nt problem). I just want find zend way to do redirect and form data cleaned.

Comment: @Vaidas Zilionis i didn't understand that from your original post